# Struggeling with proof of an Equivalent transformation

Tags: logic, solution-verification

I'm trying to proof the following equation:

$$(( ≥ ℎ ∧  = ) ∨ ( < ℎ ∧  = ))$$
$$⇕$$
$$( = ) ∨ ( ≥ ℎ)$$

It should be equivalent, but I'm struggeling proofing it.

I have got this so far:

$$( ≥ ℎ ∧  = ) ∨ ( < ℎ ∧  = )$$
$$⇕ Distributive law$$
$$(( < ℎ ∧  = ) ∨  = )∧$$
$$(( < ℎ ∧  = ) ∨  ≥ ℎ)$$
$$⇕ Distributive law$$
$$( < ℎ ∨  = ) ∧ ( =  ∨  = )∧$$
$$( < ℎ ∨  ≥ ℎ) ∧ ( =  ∨  ≥ ℎ)$$
$$⇕$$
$$( < ℎ ∨  = ) ∧ () ∧ () ∧ ( =  ∨  ≥ ℎ)$$
$$⇕ neutral$$
$$( < ℎ ∨  = ) ∧ ( =  ∨  ≥ ℎ)$$
$$⇕ Distributive law$$
$$(( =  ∨  ≥ ℎ) ∧  < ℎ)∨$$
$$(( =  ∨  ≥ ℎ) ∧  = )$$

Can someone please give me a hint. :)

Comment: Sorry. I have changed it :)

Comment: Thank you, also +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalence is not true as written (If one is considering these as placeholders for sets, then one must consider the trivial cases where certain sets are empty).

In the $\Leftarrow$ direction consider $(found = true) \wedge (left \geq right)$ which satisfies the $RHS$, but does not satisfy either of the statements on the $LHS$.

If $(found = true) \wedge (left \geq right)$, then $(( ≥ ℎ ∧  = )$ is false since we can't have $found = true$ and $found = false$.

$ ( < ℎ ∧  = ))$ is false since we can't have $left \geq right$ and $left < right$.

Hence if $(found = true) \wedge (left \geq right)$ we can't have $(( ≥ ℎ ∧  = ) ∨ ( < ℎ ∧  = ))$.

So then $(found = true) \wedge (left \geq right) \nRightarrow $

$ (( ≥ ℎ ∧  = ) ∨ ( < ℎ ∧  = ))$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Wouldn't your answer mean, that 
$$(r = 0 ∧  = )∨(runs ≥ 0 ∧  = )⇔ ru = 0 ∨ ( =  ∧ r > 0)$$ is also not equivalent? But this equation is equivalent. At least I think so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... The RHS is an OR, not an AND. You are using an AND like $$((found=true)∧(left≥right)$$ but it is $$(found=true)∨(left≥right)$$. Do I unterstand you correctly?

Comment: If an OR statement is true, then that means either one of them is true, or both are true. In this counterexample I am taking the case where both are true.

Comment: So if you want to consider that the $RHS$ is $TRUE$ and show this implies that the $LHS$ is $TRUE$, then you must show that for all cases. In the $OR$ case, this includes the case where both statements are $TRUE$. In my example, I show that in this case we have $T \implies F$, so that they cannot be logically equivalent. This would be a row of $TF$ in a truth table, for example.

Comment: I'm afraid a lot of your work is just moving contradictions around, you aren't really going anywhere in your argument. I am guessing the difficulty for you comes from the fact that the statements are in fact not equivalent, as I have explained.

Comment: Ok... Thank you. I got you. I do understand.This equation is part of a bigger task. I am using the Hoare-Logic to proof the correctnes of an algorithm. I know, that the algorithm is correct. So I need to change my statements somehow.

Comment: You're welcome upvote this if my answer was helpful. If you have a new question, make sure make a new question, instead of editing this one.